# AngularJS get current user from backend - error interceptor

Tags: angularjs, error-handling

I have the following function to get the logged in user. I have to say that I have copied the code from a tutorial - therefore I don't know exactly whats going on in background.
After a few minutes (20 min) and no request the token is not valid any more and if `getCurrentUser()` is invoked I get a white screen (HTTP 401 from backend) - my error interceptor `$httpProvider.interceptors.push(errorInterceptor);` is not invoked.

My question now would be how to handle this case. Is ist possible to force errorInterceptor- invokation in getCurrentUser() or how to handle this?

```
function getCurrentUser() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if(currentUser){
            deferred.resolve(currentUser);
        } else {
            getCurrentUserFromAPI().success(function(data) {
                if(data) {
                    currentUser = data;
                    return deferred.resolve(currentUser);
                }
            }).error(function(data) {
                var token = authTokenService.getToken();
                if(token) {
                    authTokenService.deleteToken();
                }
                return deferred.reject(data);
            });
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

**[EDIT]**

This is my interceptor at bottom and I thought that errorResponse function is always invoked when backend responses an error - e.g. HTTP 401, but this method is not invoked when function **getCurrentUser** is invoked and an HTTP 401 is response from server - therefore I get a white screen.

Actually I don't know what to do in order to prevent this white screen?
Is there any hit I can do in this case?

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myProject.error')
    .config(configure);

configure.$inject = ['$httpProvider'];

function configure($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(errorInterceptor);

    ////////////

    function errorInterceptor($injector, $q, $location) {
        var interceptor = {
                responseError: responseError
        };

        return interceptor;

        ////////////

        function responseError(response) {
            alert('responseError')
            switch(response.status) {
            case ...
            }
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    }
}
```

})();

Comment: You question is not clear.  Please elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't resolving your `deffered` when you have null data in your `.success` method.

Try this:

```
function getCurrentUser() {

    if (currentUser) return $q.when(currentUser);

    return getCurrentUserFromAPI(
               ).then(function(response) {
                       if (response.data) {
                           currentUser = response.data;
                           return currentUser;
                       } else {
                           currentUser = null;
                           throw null;
                       }     
                   },function(error) {
                       var token = authTokenService.getToken();
                       if (token) {
                           authTokenService.deleteToken();
                       };
                       throw error;
                   });
    };
};
```

**Deprecation notice**

The `.success` and `.error` methods are now deprecated in the `$http` service. Instead use the `.then`, `.catch`, and `.finally` methods. For more information see the [AngularJS $http Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Answer (score 0):

I have added this code:

```
if(resp.$$state.status == 0) {
        $location.path('/signin')
    }
```

and then it works so far (exept I reload browser view - then I am redirected to login- page) but actually I don't know what **resp.$$state.status** is and why it is 0. And also I don't know why **function(error)** or **function(success)** is not invoked - when I debug in browser success and error callback are not invoked.
Maybe someone does have an answer to this issue.

```
function getCurrentUser() {
        if (currentUser) {
            return $q.when(currentUser);
        }
    var resp = getCurrentUserFromAPI().then(function(response) {
           if (response.data) {
               currentUser = response.data;
               return currentUser;
           } else {
               currentUser = null;
               throw null;
           }     
       }, function(error) {
           var token = authTokenService.getToken();
           if (token) {
               authTokenService.deleteToken();
           }
           throw error;
       });

    if(resp.$$state.status == 0) {
        $location.path('/signin')
    }

    return resp;
    };

function getCurrentUserFromAPI() {
        return $http.get(api_config.BASE_URL + '/getCurrentLoggedUser');
    }
```